# Bootstrap media query does not take all the css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Ok, so I'm using Bootstrap 3 for one of my websites.
Everything works great, but there's something wrong with the @media query to define some css for smaller devices.

So I've included all the necessary files of bootstrap (first the bootstrap css & then my own, the js,...)

In my css I have for example:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .md-only {
        display:none;
    }
    .item-left {
        padding:0px;
    }
}
.item-left {
    padding:10px;
}
```

So what now happens is that when I add `class="md-only"` in my html the div (for example) doesn't show up on devices < 768px. However, the div with `class="item-left"` still uses the `padding:10px` and not the `padding:0px` as defined in the @media query. So it takes one css class, but not the rest.

I don't get what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the order of your rules.

Try placing the `.item-left` before the `@media`.

```css
.item-left{padding:10px;}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){  
.md-only{display:none;}  
.item-left{padding:0px;}  
}
```

```html
<div class="md-only"></div>
<div class="item-left">qweqwe</div>
```

Comment: It was that simple! Thank you!

Comment: Last rules in the cascade overwrite previous rules if they have the same specificity. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not overriding your styles. As you can see in your example, you've added the class .item-left a second time after defining it in the media query earlier thus making it obsolete.

```css
.item-left {
  padding: 10px;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .md-only {
    display: none;
  }
  .item-left {
    padding: 0px;
  }
}
```